# Wrapping Python console/plotting in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, matplotlib

I am looking to build a graphical frontend for some python functionality.
Since I am very proficient in HTML/CSS/JS I decided I might check this out as a possibility.

The main idea is to make it easier to explore data/variables, I am thinking of a datagrid for example. 
I was also thinking of creating a GUI for things such as plotting with matplotlib (ie: Choose variable for X axis, choose variable for Y axis, pick a color from a dropdown, ...) in order to cut out some of the tediousness in exploring data with several variables.

I would then probably use something like [Node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) to make a desktop application out of it if possible (and if not, just keep it as a browser project, perhaps).

Essentially what it would boil down to is kind of creating an IDE for python, specialized for data exploration/plotting and perhaps data manipulation.

An example I found for a web-based python console is [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/Python)

However I have spent a fair amount of time looking for viable ways to go about this, since sending and receiving data from the python interpreter wouldn't be too hard, but it might get a bit harder for exploring variables or plotting data.

So the question is: Are there any projects or libraries out there to facilitate this kind of functionality, or which provide a good starting point for interacting with Python through JavaScript? Are there any pointers you guys can give me to make the experience for users as seamless as possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You might take a look at how IPython notebooks work.  These provide a nice web-based interface for python.  They've started to add interactive plot functionality.  This makes it a bit more dynamic than the older: run cell, edit cell, run cell ... workflow.  Check out, [link](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/5665) for a partial introduction to what's going on under the hood.